# calling data from nested .json using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm new one to work with JSON and getting stuck that how to call JSON data from nested `.json` file. please check the code below ...

**JSON FORMAT**

```
{

    "hotels": {
        "category": [{
            "name": "Exotic and Luxurious",
            "products": [{
                "name": "Sofitel L'Imperial Resort and Spa",
                "budget": "Luxery",
                "location": "flic en flac",
                "price": "71500"
            }, {
                "name": "Shanti Maurice a Nira Resort",
                "budget": "Luxery",
                "location": "Chemin Grenier",
                "price": "88500"
            }]
        },{
            "name": "In the Tourist Hub",
            "products": [{
                "name": "Sofitel L'Imperial Resort and Spa",
                "budget": "Luxery",
                "location": "flic en flac",
                "price": "71500"
            }, {
                "name": "Shanti Maurice a Nira Resort",
                "budget": "Luxery",
                "location": "Chemin Grenier",
                "price": "88500"
            }]
        },{
            "name": "Close to the Beach and Market",
            "products": [{
                "name": "Sofitel L'Imperial Resort and Spa",
                "budget": "Luxery",
                "location": "flic en flac",
                "price": "71500"
            }, {
                "name": "Shanti Maurice a Nira Resort",
                "budget": "Luxery",
                "location": "Chemin Grenier",
                "price": "88500"
            }]
        },{
            "name": "Private and Peaceful",
            "products": [{
                "name": "Sofitel L'Imperial Resort and Spa",
                "budget": "Luxery",
                "location": "flic en flac",
                "price": "71500"
            }, {
                "name": "Shanti Maurice a Nira Resort",
                "budget": "Luxery",
                "location": "Chemin Grenier",
                "price": "88500"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

**AJAX CODE**

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'hotels.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success : function(data){

        /*jQuery(data).each(function(index, value){
            console.log(value.hotels.name);
        })*/
        //console.log(data.hotels.category[1].name);
        //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        var i = 0;
        jQuery(data.hotels.category).each(function(){
            jQuery('.theme ul').append('<li data-role="'+data.hotels.category[i].name+'">'+data.hotels.category[i].name+'</li>');
            i++;
        })
        jQuery(data.hotels.category).each(function(){
            jQuery('.budget ul').append('<li data-role="'+data.hotels.category[i].name.products[0].name+'">'+data.hotels.category[i].name.products[0].name+'</li>');
            i++;
        })
    }
    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="theme">
<p>Hotel experience theme</p>
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>

    <div class="budget">
    <p>Budget</p>
        <ul>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

I want to call name data from products which is defined in category in `<li>` of `budget` div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
jQuery(data.hotels.category).each(function() {...});
```

to:

```
jQuery.each(data.hotels.category, function() {...});
```

The first form is for looping over DOM elements in a selection, the second form is for looping over Javascript arrays and objects.

And within the function, you can use `this` to refer to the element, you don't need to use `data.hotels.category[i]`.

But if you continue to use `data.hotels.category[i]`, you need to set `i` back to `0` before the second loop. Or you could just do everything in one loop. And `.each()` passes the array index to the function, so you don't need your own variable.

Finally, `products` is not a sub-property of the `name` property.

The final result of fixing and simplifying this should be:

```
    jQuery.each(data.hotels.category, function(){
        jQuery('.theme ul').append('<li data-role="'+this.name+'">'+this.name+'</li>');
        jQuery('.budget ul').append('<li data-role="'+this.products[0].name+'">'+this.products[0].name+'</li>');
    });
```

Comment: hi barmar thank u sp much for ur help but its still giving error

colsole saying that " jQuery('.budget ul').append('<li data-role="'+this.name.products[0].name+'">'+this.name.products[0].name+'</li>');"

"TypeError: this.name.products is undefined"

Comment: I fixed that in my last edit. Don't you see where I wrote "Finally, products is not a sub-property of the name property"?

Comment: It should be `this.products[0].name`, not `this.name.products[0].name`.

Answer (score 1):

The `products` belong to `category` directly so you don't have to pass by `name` to get it, you should go directly to it, so try to replace :

```
data.hotels.category[i].name.products[0].name
```

BY :

```
data.hotels.category[i].products[0].name
```

Hope this helps.